# Closing a USB serial port leaves the port unavailable

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

My app uses USB based serial ports to connect to physical hardware devices. I can open any valid USB port and communicate with the external devices. However, when I close the connection, the USB port is left in some sort of indeterminate state for some time, and during that time further attempts to reconnect result in the "Access to port "COM--" is denied" error. However, after some few seconds, attempting to reconnect is successful. How can I determine WHEN the USB port will again support a new connection?

The code looks like this:

```
    private void Setup(string Port)
    {
        bool ValidPort = false;
        int CloseSleep = 10;

        _PortName = Port;
        _PortType = this;

        string[] AvailablePorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();  

        foreach(string aPort in AvailablePorts)
        {
            if (aPort == _PortName)
            {
                // The required port is listed in the list of available ports)
                ValidPort = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (ValidPort)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_ThePort != null)
                {
                    _ThePort.Close();
                    _ThePort.DataReceived -= ReceivedDataEventHandler;

                    while(CloseSleep-- > 0)
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

                    _ThePort.Dispose();
                    _ThePort = null;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EMS_Config_Tool.ModalDialog md = new EMS_Config_Tool.ModalDialog("Closing Port: " + ex.Message, "System Exception");
                md.ShowDialog();
            }

            System.IO.Ports.SerialPort TheNewPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(Port, 38400);

            // Setup the event handlers from Tx and Rx
            Handler.DataOutEvent    += CommsSender;
            TheNewPort.DataReceived += ReceivedDataEventHandler;

            TheNewPort.DataBits  = 8;
            TheNewPort.Parity    = Parity.None;
            TheNewPort.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
            TheNewPort.StopBits  = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;

            // We will try 3 times to open the port, and report an error if we fail to open the port
            try
            {
                TheNewPort.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                try
                {
                    TheNewPort.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    try
                    {
                        TheNewPort.Open();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        EMS_Config_Tool.ModalDialog md = new EMS_Config_Tool.ModalDialog("Opening Port: " + ex.Message, "System Exception");

                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The final catch statement is where the error about Access being denied is issued. Note my attempt to retry opening the port 3 times doesn't really help. If I leave the port alone for about 5 to 10 seconds and retry calling the Setup method it succeeds immediately.

Comment: Serial port drivers (especially USB serial ports) are notoriously bad.  Unless it's a expensive one, it's probably based on the (broken) FTTI (?) driver source, which has many issues.   If the only way you can get it to work is wait for 5 or 10 seconds between uses, then you've probably got the best answer already.

Comment: It's FTDI and oh boy. Why add a delay before calling `_ThePort.Dispose()` ? The code needs a bit of cleanup anyway. Retries could be in a loop, not nested one inside another.

Comment: I agree about the "cleanup".... what I was attempting was a Q&D attempt to see if waiting for the close before the dispose would help (it didn't :)...but after my initial post I reworked it into something a bit more acceptable...(perhaps)

Comment: I've just been informed by one of our hardware engineers that our USB is not FTDI based, but is embedded in the RX processor, and handled as a software task..... Should I be happy? Nah, still doesn't work well....but perhaps (being a software task) it can be looked at again and "cleaned up" to make it work better....

Answer (score 0):

As @Neil said, there are many issues. The best thing to do, in my point of view, is to put the search in a loop, and as soon as the port can be opened, it will be.

I used to do like this :

```
public Task WaitingPort()
{
    while (port is null)
        {
            port = CheckPort();
        }
}

private SerialPort CheckPort()
{
    string[] listPort = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    foreach(string namePort in listPort)
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort(namePort, 9600);
        if (!port.IsOpen)
        {
            try
            {
                port.Open();
                port.ReadTimeout = 1500;
                string data = port.Readline();
                // I programmed my device to send an "A" until it receives
                // "777" to be able to recognize it once opened
                if (data.Substring(0, 1) == "A") 
                {
                    port.ReadTimeout = 200;
                    port.Write("777"); // to make it stop sending "A"
                    return port;
                }
                else
                {
                port.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                port.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Of course, this is just some kind of a template which you have to reshape to your use

Answer (score 0):

I have amended my code to use a constrained loop to give it a better chance to work, which it usually does. I was hoping that there was a better way to do it, as I tend to have pretty impatient users who will be posting defect reports if they have to wait 5 or 10 seconds to make a connection....

```
            // We will try several times to open the port, upto 10 times over 5 seconds, and report an error if we finally fail to open the port
            try
            {
                TheNewPort.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RetryOpenTimer.Interval = 500;
                RetryCount = 10;
                RetryOpenTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(RetryOpenTimer_Elapsed);
                WaitForOpen = true;
                RetryOpenTimer.Start();

                while (WaitForOpen && RetryCount > 0)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
                if (WaitForOpen)
                {
                    EMS_Config_Tool.ModalDialog md = new EMS_Config_Tool.ModalDialog("Opening Port: " + ex.Message, "System Exception");
                    return;
                }
            }
```

...

```
    void RetryOpenTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        RetryOpenTimer.Stop();
        RetryOpenTimer.Elapsed -= RetryOpenTimer_Elapsed;

        try
        {
            if (RetryCount-- > 0)
            {
                TheNewPort.Open();

                WaitForOpen = false;
            }
            else
                return;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            RetryOpenTimer.Start();
            RetryOpenTimer.Elapsed += RetryOpenTimer_Elapsed;
        }
    }
```